# How to run CLI commands from the launcher?

Tags: launcher

I press ALT+F2 key on my keyboard, and get the launcher HUD up. From there I enter a command as I would in a shell, specifically `vlc ~/Music/* -Z`. If done from a shell, vlc starts and begins to play music.

However, when done from the launcher, VLC replies:

> File reading failed:
>
> VLC could not open the file "/home/[username]/Music/*". (No such file or directory)
> user
> Your input can't be opened:
>
> VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///home/[username]/Music/%2A'. Check the log for details.

I can't quite figure out what the difference is.

Comment: Try `vlc --reset`

Comment: In my version, 2.0.1, --reset is not a valid option.

Comment: `sh -c "vlc ~/Music/* -Z"` should work, but there is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-place-applications/+bug/778202), so quoting doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else pointed it out, but then removed their answer, so I'll add it again.

The reason this particular command fails is that the launcher doesn't use a shell, which means that VLC is literally trying to load a file *named* *, as opposed to globbing the star into a file list.

A workaround is to call a shell instead, as elmicha pointed out in a comment. `sh -c "vlc ~/Music/* -Z"` would do this. This however fails due to a bug, again see elmichas comment.

In this particular case, since VLC will recursively traverse directories, the same result can be achieved with `vlc ~/Music`, which works fine without a shell, and is much simpler.